# Can we get a cocos2d-x tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

This port is growing by the days and a lot people unsure about it just uses cocos2d and cocos2d-iphone, whose implementation in essentially different.

I would create it but I'm still working my way to 300, asking and answering 2d-x questions mostly.

Thank you.

Comment: what questions specifically need it

Comment: Anything related to selectors just for starters, and the specific implementations of delegates and certain functions based off which platform we are in.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of non documented or non implemented functions nobody in the community speaks about, that in cocos2d are basic or trivial.

Comment: I meant which questions on the site need the tag.  You can't just "add a tag" without applying it to a question.

Comment: I think somebody else already did it :) http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x

Answer (score 2):

[Yes, we can!](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x)

This question felt lonely without an answer.